# Regex for string which can contains either numbers, letters or a combination of both. Do not include symbols or special characters

Tags: regex

I need to validate Username for an user for below condition.

- username can contain letters, numbers or combination of both.
- Username must not contain any special characters such as @ $ % ^ & * () + = ‘ ~ - _"

**Valid Examples:**
Test123

123Test

T123est

**Invalid Examples:**

Test@%^&123

@#$Test

Test123@#$%^

**Below is the expression I tried:**

/[a-zA-Z\d]+/

/[^@$%^&*()+=‘~-_"]*/

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$/
```

^ and $ marks, start and end of string and are needed to not match part of the input.

Edit: Updated as commenters suggested as I didn't remember that underscore was part of \w

Comment: I suppose a valid username cannot be empty though. Also note that `\w` is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so includes digits **and** the underscore. I think you need `^[A-Za-z\d]+$`.

Comment: Or \b[\w-[_]]+\b
to check "words" rather than complete segments